# PSA: advanced custom fields the_repeater_field iterates too often

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

This is not a question, but an answer, for those who have the same problems.

I had a problem with the_repeater_field() function from ACF.
I used to have a custom post with a custom field repeater, where the customer could put in some dates for presentations etc.

Now he wanted to have the same with different services, so I created some new date posts for each service. Suddenly all dates would be repeated 3 times.

So the problem was while(has_posts()); for my custom post type. Apparently it went through each post of that custom post type and then called the repeater field function.

Here is the WRONG code for reference: 
    //get custom posts beforehand 
    //took out customerinformation beforehand and replaced everything with placeholder

```
if($getposts->have_posts())
{
     while(has_posts()){ //<--- this is wrong
        $getposts -> the_post();
        $theID = get_page_by_title( 'pagetitle', '', 'customposttype' );

        //$type is the type of date, could be online or in person

        if(get_field($type, $theID->ID)){
            while(the_repeater_field($type, $theID->ID)){

                $date = get_sub_field('date');
                $time = get_sub_field('time');
                $header = get_sub_field('header');
                $email = get_sub_field('email_text');


                if($today <= $date)
                {


                    $return .= "<a href='mailto:email@email.com?subject=".$header."&body=".$email."'>".$date." - ".$time. " Uhr </a></br>";
                }
            }
          } 
       }
}
```

Hope I could help someone, who might encounter a similar problem. Couldn't find anything online. Though it is a rookie mistake to have that while loop in there. Didnt do harm for months because it was only for one service.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code:

```
if($getposts->have_posts())
  {
    $getposts -> the_post();
    $theID = get_page_by_title( 'pagetitle', '', 'customposttype' );

    //$type is the type of date, could be online or in person

    if(get_field($type, $theID->ID)){
        while(the_repeater_field($type, $theID->ID)){

            $date = get_sub_field('date');
            $time = get_sub_field('time');
            $header = get_sub_field('header');
            $email = get_sub_field('email_text');


            if($today <= $date)
            {


                $return .= "<a href='mailto:email@email.com?subject=".$header."&body=".$email."'>".$date." - ".$time. " Uhr </a></br>";
            }
        }
      } 
   }
```